# Controlar excepción NOT NUMBER PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

¿Como controlar la excepción cuando una variable de sustitución recibe una cadena de caracteres?

Buenas, en un bloque anónimo he introducido varias variables de sustitución, una de ellas es de tipo NUMBER y no doy con la tecla para controlar que la variable recibe un valor numerico. He probado con "WHEN OTHERS THEN", creando la excepción usando RAISE APPLICATION ERROR, anidando IFS para que si no entra vaya al else (como si fuera el error), y bueno, no doy con la clave y me parece lo más básico.

Edito: Estoy utilizando Oracle SQL Developer.

Aquí el bloque anónimo de ejemplo:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
-- Pido el número
  dato_numerico NUMBER := &Dime_un_numero;

-- Excepción por si es negativo
  numero_negativo EXCEPTION;

BEGIN

  IF dato_numerico < 0 THEN
    RAISE numero_negativo;
  END IF;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El número es: '||dato_numerico);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN numero_negativo THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El número no puede ser negativo');

END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías recibir el valor como texto y posteriormente intentar convertirlo a numérico, en caso tal de que la conversión falle, entonces no sera un numero valido.

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
--
DECLARE
  dato_raw      VARCHAR2(4000);
  dato_numerico NUMBER;
  -- Excepciones
  numero_negativo EXCEPTION; -- Excepción por si es negativo
  error_conversion EXCEPTION; -- Error en caso de que no sea posible convertir a numerico
  -- Inicializar excepciones
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(error_conversion, -06502);
BEGIN
  dato_raw := '&Dime_un_numero';
  dato_numerico := TO_NUMBER(dato_raw);
  --
  IF dato_numerico < 0 THEN
    RAISE numero_negativo;
  END IF;
  --
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El número es: '||dato_numerico);
  --
EXCEPTION
  WHEN numero_negativo THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El número no puede ser negativo');
  WHEN error_conversion THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Debe ingresar un numero valido');
END;
```